# Google Cloud Datastore .... time complexity for read

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

Is Google Cloud Store suitable for storing & retrieving time series data (data that is stored sequentially)?

I looked online and couldnt find any details as to whether they index or fragment data that could affect read speed?

Specifically, I need to lookup a key => property value in O(1).

Comment: I don't really see how this is a duplicate.  fetching an object by key is generally considered constant time (though infrastructure latencies do come into play - https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown  the main problem you may face is the limit of a single inequality filter.  Which prohibits the use of a simple query to find records falling within a date range.

Comment: Also keys that are sequential can cause slow downs on write due to tablet contention.  That is why google introduced sparse keys. See discussion in groups - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Yt9W204jips

Comment: The single inequality filter applies to a field, not to an inequality operation though, right? So you can do this - date > ? and date < ?, you just can't do startDate < ? and endDate > ?

Comment: I'm also looking for that. I want to store market data in key value: [barOpenTime] ["Open High Low Close Volume"].

Answer (score 1):

[Google Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) (note that this is different from [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/)) supports O(1) lookup of entities and queries that are O(N) where N is the number of results.

Inequality filters are supported [on at most one property](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#Datastore_Restrictions_on_queries), and you can specify both an upper and lower bound on that property. However, large numbers of sequential writes (such as bulk deletes or an index on write time) may slow down range queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could store an arbitrarily large number of keys => value pairs in Google Cloud Storage in a bucket with the key being the object name and the value being the contents. If the object names were predictable, orderable timestamps, you could even list an arbitrary range of dates to get a list of keys and then look up their values. If you stored the values as metadata, you could even get the values in the list operation.

That said, cloud blob storage solutions like S3 or GCS are not the optimal way to store time series data. It will work, and individual lookups will be pretty close to constant time, but a specialized time series database or even a standard relational database will almost certainly be more performant for tables of data by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Because I don't need to make any aggregation, I'm considering storing the data as raw bytes in each key - indexed by time - and then performing a O(1) calculation to grab a range. My experiences with relational databases make me think that as the DB scales, read operations are going to get expensive , therefore maybe inappropriate.

Comment: predictable ordered timestamps as keys? That makes me shudder. Read this if you want a scalable database https://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/